# Unable to take RDP from the desktop to a Server

Tags: windows

Unable to take RDP from the Desktop to a Server. It say The Remote Session is terminated Due to the following error. The disconnection error : 1800. Please suggest what to do and how to resolve this?????

Comment: there's nowhere near enough information here, come on, detail us up!

Comment: What is the desktop is version and what server is r u running. Update to the latest rdp version that is compatible with the server and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780927(WS.10).aspx

Does your error sound like any of these?  You could try the following steps:

- Make sure that remote access is enabled
- Reboot the server- this fixes 90% of the problems with Windows servers
- Attempt to connect using a different username

  - You could be denied access
- Attempt to connect using a different computer and your username

  - If this works, try reinstalling your RDP client
- Attempt to connect using a different computer and a different username

  - If this works, try reinstalling your RDP client and connect using a different username on your computer

These are only a few simple steps you could try that would give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing client RDP v6.0.